# Problems with JavaScript object destructuring

Tags: javascript

```js
let pppp = {
    name: "duanxiao",
    age: 1,
    job: {
        title: "~~~"
    }
};
let ppppCopy = {};

({
    name: ppppCopy.name,
    age: ppppCopy.age,
    job: ppppCopy.job
} = pppp);

pppp.job.title = "Hacker";

console.log(pppp);
console.log(ppppCopy);
```

The output values ​​are the same.

**Why modifying the value of one object, the other object will also be modified?**

Whenever I modify the value of one object, the value of the other object is also modified.

Comment: Can't reproduce that. `ppppCopy` doesn't contain anything in the `jbo` property

Comment: sorry should be job, not jbo

Comment: This is normal as you are not copying the value from that object but a reference to that key in the object.

Comment: The `job` object will be passed by reference. Therefore it will affect both the original and "copy" object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you `pppp` and `ppppCopy` holds the same reference of `job` property. Changing at one location will impact another. You can achieve your intended outcome with below code using ES6 spread operator,

```
let pppp = {
    name: "duanxiao",
    age: 1,
    job: {
        title: "~~~"
    }
};

const ppppCopy = {
  ...pppp,
  job: { ...pppp.job },
};
```

With this, updating `pppp.job.title` will not impact `ppppCopy.job.title`.

You can also use the traditional way like `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(pppp))`, but you need to be more cautious while using this approach as it strips down the function property

Comment: yes,it is a shallow copy. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In JS, and many other languages, you have data types that store by value, like Number and other primitive types. Some data types stored by reference, like Arrays, Object.

By destructing `pppp` you just passing the reference to the inner `job` object, and not duplicating it, so technically its the same `job` object in `pppp` and `ppppCopy`.

Here I added a manipulation to a primitive, and you can see that there is a difference.

```js
let pppp = {
    name: "duanxiao",
    age: 1,
    job: {
        title: "~~~"
    }
};
let ppppCopy = {};

({
    name: ppppCopy.name,
    age: ppppCopy.age,
    job: ppppCopy.job
} = pppp);

pppp.job.title = "Hacker";
pppp.age = 123;

console.log(pppp);
console.log(ppppCopy);
```

[Here is another good answer related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Comment: Thanks, that is, this is a shallow copy right? 

Answer (score 0):

Since objects are non-primitive data types javascript makes a reference of the original object when you make a copy using the assignment operator as you have done in your case. In order to avoid shallow copying you can use the spread operator i.e. `let copy = { ...original}`  or you can use the assign method i.e. `let copy = Object.assign({}, original)`  but both of these fail when you have a nested object. In order to deep copy a nested object you need to do it as Edoardo pointed out above but that will fail too when there is a function in your object. Ravindra's method can also be used, but it will be a hassle when you have multiple nested objects.

The best way to do it in my opinion is to use lodash `_.cloneDeep()` method. You can read more about it [here](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep)

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is very detailed.I am a beginner and I don't understand it deeply.

Answer (score -1):

The only way is to use JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(pppp));

```
    name: "duanxiao",
    age: 1,
    job: {
        title: "~~~"
    }
};
let ppppCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(pppp));



pppp.job.title = "Hacker";

console.log(pppp);
console.log(ppppCopy);
```

Comment: Why the **only** way?

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. "The only way" to achieve what?

Comment: What I mean is why one object is modified, and the other object will change. Because it is a shallow copy, right?

Comment: Feel free to add all clarification to your answer by editing it